# Fullscreen mode loaded when opening Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fullscreen

Is it possible to make a flash player go full screen (not in browser)?
Would there be any bug / error on different version of Flash player?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if not, you could always make a simple .exe to load your .swf and make that maximized without borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI!

```
stage.displayMode = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
```

Available **only in Adobe AIR.** 
It allows you to listen to keyboard events (meaning you can also type inside text boxes etc..)

---

```
stage.displayMode = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Available in any AS3 based flash file (starting from flash 9)
There is no issue with using it, except you **cannot use the keybard**.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with fullscreen mode's in flash the main thing to bear in mind is to make your application have liquid layouts which re-act to the Event.RESIZE. Then when you listen for that event re-lay out your application to the new ( fullscreen ) width and height.

To do this you would change the stage.displayMode to [StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState)

Answer (score 0):

In Flash player it's Ctrl-F, as menu suggests, so it's certainly possible. Have you tried stage.displayMode = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE? [StageDisplayState doc](http://127.0.0.1:57922/help/nftopic/com.adobe.flexbuilder.help/langref/index.html?flash/display/StageDisplayState.html) says it's here from version 9.0.28.0.

Comment: FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE is only available in AIR.